# Совместимость проектов Eclipse и Idea

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

Почему код

```
public class Krot{
    public void Krotik(){
        System.out.println("JJJ");
    }
}
```

в Eclipse виден без ошибок, а в IDEA ругается на "System"? Ошибка "Cannot resolve symbol "System"".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Настройте JDK (Java SDK) для проекта. JDK должно быть видно в зависимостях проекта и во вкладке Classpath должны быть .jar файлы. Если вкладка пустая, переустановите JDK, удалите конфигурацию в IDEA и добавьте ее снова.

[image: jdk]

[image: project]

[image: module]